# Removing the 1st element then 1st and 2nd element from a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My aim is to remove the 1st element of a list and then the first and second element of a list etc. So a list entered like this: `[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]` will return a list like this: `[[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]`
I have tried many things but none work well

Comment: Sounds like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Are you just looking for `itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 2)`

Comment: "remove the 1st element of a list and then the first and second element of a list etc." Sorry, I can't follow the description. In the first step, we remove `[1,1]`, leaving `[[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]`; then in the second step we remove... the first and second elements of that? which are `[1,2],[1,3]`? so that leaves `[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]`? But you expect `[1,2]` to remain in the result... please clarify.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel apologies I meant it should remove the repeated elements, so the first element of the lists beginning with the value 1. And then after it should remove two elements of the list where the lists begin with the value 2 etc

Comment: your question is still vexingly vague. "it should remove the repeated elements": but there are no *repeated* elements in your input list. what should an input of [[2,0],[1,0]] yield?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. Out of all the sub-lists that start with a 1, remove the first; of the sub-lists starting with a 2, remove the first two, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this :

```
list1 = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
list2 = []

keep_index = 1
increment = 0
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if i == keep_index:
        list2.append(list1[i])
        increment += 2 if keep_index == 2 else 1
        keep_index += increment
print(list2)
```

And as @schwobaseggl commented, this code could be what you are looking for :

```
import itertools
itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3], 2) # combinations of 2 elements (without repeats)
```

Comment: i don't understand why you consider that invocation of itertools.combinations a direct solution to the *problem* when it just happens to solve one *instance of his problem*. (otherwise, wouldn't the literal [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]] also solve the problem?) that is, unless i'm misunderstanding the question altogether.

Comment: Answer edited...

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

def f( l ): 
    def elements_to_remove():
        for i in itertools.count( 1 ): 
            yield from itertools.repeat( i, i )

    def _g():
        es = elements_to_remove()

        skip = None
        e = next( es )

        while True:
            skip = (yield not skip)[0] == e
            e    = next( es ) if skip else e

    g = _g()
    next( g )
    return list( filter( g.send, l ) )

inputs = [] 
inputs.append( [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]] )
inputs.append( [[0,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]] )
inputs.append( [[2,0],[1,0]] )

for input in inputs:
    print( f"{input} -> {f(input)}" )
```

I *think* f is a function you are looking for based on your description. Here is the output of the above script:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]] -> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]] -> [[0, 0], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
[[2, 0], [1, 0]] -> [[2, 0]]
```

. Note that the input is NOT modified in place; you'd need to adapt the code a little if you want that.